# \phantom not giving correct space?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, white-space, alignat, phantom

The code

```latex
\begin{alignat*}{2}
d\bigl(x^{(j)}_j, x^{(i)}_i\bigr)
    & \le d\bigl(x^{(j)}_j, x^{(i)}_j\bigr) + d\bigl(x^{(i)}_j, x^{(i)}_i\bigr)\\
    & < d\bigl(x^{(j)}_j, x^{(j)}_k\bigr) + d\bigl(x^{(j)}_k, x^{(i)}_k\bigr) + d\bigl(x^{(i)}_k, x^{(i)}_j\bigr) & \text{$k$ arbitrary}\\
    & \phantom{d\bigl(x^{(j)}_j, x^{(j)}_k\bigr) + d\bigl(x^{(j)}_k, x^{(i)}_k\bigr)} {}+ 1/i & \text{let $j\ge i$}\\
    & < 1/j + d\bigl(x^{(j)}_k, x^{(i)}_k\bigr) + 1/j +1/i & \text{let $k\ge j$}\\
    & \le 2/i + \hat d\bigl( \overline{x^{(j)}}, \overline{x^{(i)}} \bigr) + 1/i & \text{taking $k\to \infty$}\\
    & < 2/j + 2/i & \text{since $j\ge i$}
\end{alignat*}
```

produces:

[image]

What is the cause of this miscalculated width of the box that `\phantom` creates? And how to get `+ 1/i` placed directly below the `+` that appears in the above line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to put `{}<` at the beginning of the `\phantom`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
d\bigl(x^{(j)}_j, x^{(i)}_i\bigr)
  & \le d\bigl(x^{(j)}_j, x^{(i)}_j\bigr) + d\bigl(x^{(i)}_j, x^{(i)}_i\bigr)\\
  & < d\bigl(x^{(j)}_j, x^{(j)}_k\bigr)
    + d\bigl(x^{(j)}_k, x^{(i)}_k\bigr)
    + d\bigl(x^{(i)}_k, x^{(i)}_j\bigr) & \text{$k$ arbitrary}\\
  & \phantom{{}< d\bigl(x^{(j)}_j, x^{(j)}_k\bigr)
               + d\bigl(x^{(j)}_k, x^{(i)}_k\bigr)}
    + 1/i & \text{let $j\ge i$}\\
  & < 1/j + d\bigl(x^{(j)}_k, x^{(i)}_k\bigr) + 1/j +1/i & \text{let $k\ge j$}\\
  & \le 2/i + \hat d\bigl( \overline{x^{(j)}}, \overline{x^{(i)}} \bigr)
    + 1/i & \text{taking $k\to \infty$}\\
  & < 2/j + 2/i & \text{since $j\ge i$}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A better version with no `\big` delimiter and a couple of thin spaces next to the overlined symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
d(x^{(j)}_j, x^{(i)}_i)
  & \le d(x^{(j)}_j, x^{(i)}_j) + d(x^{(i)}_j, x^{(i)}_i)\\
  & < d(x^{(j)}_j, x^{(j)}_k)
    + d(x^{(j)}_k, x^{(i)}_k)
    + d(x^{(i)}_k, x^{(i)}_j) & \text{$k$ arbitrary}\\
  & \phantom{{}< d(x^{(j)}_j, x^{(j)}_k)
               + d(x^{(j)}_k, x^{(i)}_k)}
    + 1/i & \text{let $j\ge i$}\\
  & < 1/j + d(x^{(j)}_k, x^{(i)}_k) + 1/j +1/i & \text{let $k\ge j$}\\
  & \le 2/i + \hat d(\, \overline{x^{(j)}}, \overline{x^{(i)}}\, )
    + 1/i & \text{taking $k\to \infty$}\\
  & < 2/j + 2/i & \text{since $j\ge i$}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really dig the suggestion to have thin spaces around the overlined things. Wish I could upvote it one more time just for this!